# MS CRM Dashboard - Single Full Screen IFRAME

Tags: dynamics-crm, dashboard, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to create a Microsoft CRM dashboard that contains only a single IFRAME.

The IFRAME should fill the area and only display the inner IFRAME scroll bar.

However, I am seeing double scroll bars. One for the dashboard tab area and one for the IFRAME.

**Is there a way to create a CRM dashboard that would contain only one element that fills the available space (without overflow or scrolling)?**

#### Observation:

// if I were able to modify the following CSS to remove the overflow css value in CRM it might work
.ms-crm-FormBodyContainer { /* overflow: auto; */ }

#### Context:

I am using CRM 2013 On-Premise with a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the SiteMap and add a subarea but instead of connecting it to a entity you can specify a URL.  In this case the URL is a Web Resource or the URL you use for the iFrame.  The XRMToolKit has a GUI sitemap editor.  You can download it here [http://xrmtoolbox.codeplex.com/releases/view/611881](http://xrmtoolbox.codeplex.com/re)

The picture I attached shows an example using this technique.

[image]leases/view/611881